# Export dataset to CSV in C

Tags: beginner, c, csv

I've just learnt the basics of C and I've built a working program that reads the dataset provided by my lecturer and exports it out to a CSV.

However, he said that this could've been simplified (a lot!) to just print out the data values in the required columns (x, y, z). But I don't see how that could work given my set up.

This is my first time coding (I'm a health student) and am a little overwhelmed. As I said, I'd just like my code to be reviewed and ways to make it simpler and just 'print out' the values.

Void **create_CSV** and **int main** are created by myself, whereas **gen_sally** is created by my lecturer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void gen_sally( int xs, int ys, int zs, int time, float *sally )
/*
 *  Gen_Sally creates a vector field of dimension [xs,ys,zs,3] from
 *  a proceedural function. By passing in different time arguements,
 *  a slightly different and rotating field is created.
 *
 *  The magnitude of the vector field is highest at some funnel shape
 *  and values range from 0.0 to around 0.4 (I think).
 *
 *  I just wrote these comments, 8 years after I wrote the function.
 *  
 *  Developed by Sally of Sally University
 *
 */
{
  float x, y, z;
  int ix, iy, iz;
  float r, xc, yc, scale, temp, z0;
  float r2 = 8;
  float SMALL = 0.00000000001;
  float xdelta = 1.0 / (xs-1.0);
  float ydelta = 1.0 / (ys-1.0);
  float zdelta = 1.0 / (zs-1.0);

  for( iz = 0; iz < zs; iz++ )
  {
     z = iz * zdelta;                        // map z to 0->1
     xc = 0.5 + 0.1*sin(0.04*time+10.0*z);   // For each z-slice, determine the spiral circle.
     yc = 0.5 + 0.1*cos(0.03*time+3.0*z);    //    (xc,yc) determine the center of the circle.
     r = 0.1 + 0.4 * z*z + 0.1 * z * sin(8.0*z); //  The radius also changes at each z-slice.
     r2 = 0.2 + 0.1*z;                           //    r is the center radius, r2 is for damping
     for( iy = 0; iy < ys; iy++ )
     {
        y = iy * ydelta;
        for( ix = 0; ix < xs; ix++ )
        {
            x = ix * xdelta;
            temp = sqrt( (y-yc)*(y-yc) + (x-xc)*(x-xc) );
            scale = fabs( r - temp );
/*
 *  I do not like this next line. It produces a discontinuity 
 *  in the magnitude. Fix it later.
 *
 */
           if ( scale > r2 )
              scale = 0.8 - scale;
           else
              scale = 1.0;
            z0 = 0.1 * (0.1 - temp*z );
           if ( z0 < 0.0 )  z0 = 0.0;
           temp = sqrt( temp*temp + z0*z0 );
            scale = (r + r2 - temp) * scale / (temp + SMALL);
            scale = scale / (1+z);
           *sally++ = scale * (y-yc) + 0.1*(x-xc);
           *sally++ = scale * -(x-xc) + 0.1*(y-yc);
           *sally++ = scale * z0;
        }
     }
  }
}


void create_csv(char* filename,float *sally, int size){

    printf("1");

    printf("\n Creating %s.csv file",filename);

    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen(filename,"w");

    fprintf(fp,"X,Y,Z\n");
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    for(i = 0; i< size; i++){
        if(sally[i] == 0){
            fprintf(fp,"0");
        } else {
            fprintf(fp,"%f",sally[i]);
        }
            counter++;
            if(counter == 3){
                fprintf(fp, "\n");
                counter = 0;
        } else {
            fprintf(fp,",");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n %sfile created",filename);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf("1\n");
    //read from args
    int xs;
    int ys;
    int zs;
    int time;
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&xs);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&ys);
    sscanf(argv[3],"%d",&zs);
    sscanf(argv[4],"%d",&time); // Is a constant, will always be reads as 1


    int arraySize = xs*ys*zs*1;

    //allocate memeory for array. This is done so that stack memory doesn't run out.'
    float* sally;
    sally = (float*)malloc((arraySize) * sizeof(float));

    //runs the code. One of the args is a pointer so no return type is needed. 
    gen_sally(xs,ys,zs,time,sally);

    //create varibles for file generation
    char filename[20] = "results.csv";
    create_csv(filename, sally, arraySize);

    free(sally);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `create_csv` as there is no `create_sally` function.

Comment: Thank you. Still doesn't help with my query though.

Answer (score 2):

In `main()` there is the line

```
    int arraySize = xs*ys*zs*1;
```

Anything times 1 is itself so there is no reason to multiply by 1.

In the `create_csv()` function, the variable `counter` is not needed - the variable `i` can be used instead by using the modulo operator:

```
    if (i % 3) {
        fprintf(fp, ",");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
```

An alternate simplification of this could be:

```
    fprintf(fp, "%c",  (i % 3)? ',' : '\n');
```

Also in `create_csv()`, you could get by with a single `printf()` statement rather than two:

```
    printf("1\n Creating %s.csv file\n", filename);
```

In `main()`, a better programming practice for the `malloc()` would be to use

```
sizeof *sally
```

rather than

```
sizeof(float)
```

because the type of `sally` may change at some point; by using `*sally` only one line of code needs to change rather than multiple lines of code. The `cast` of the result from `malloc()` is not necessary.

```
    float* sally;
    sally = malloc((sizeof *sally) * arraySize);
```

This code is questionable:

```
    if (sally[i] == 0) {
        fprintf(fp, "0");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(fp, "%f", sally[i]);
    }
```

because it is comparing integer zero with a float variable, it might be safer to use 0.0 in the comparison. The current code may not work properly on all computers.

Was it a requirement to write a zero value as `0`? If not, the code can be further simplified to

```
void create_csv(char* filename, float *sally, int size) {
    printf("1\n Creating %s.csv file\n", filename);

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    fprintf(fp, "X,Y,Z\n");
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%f%c", sally[i], (i % 3) ? ',' : '\n');
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n %sfile created", filename);
}
```

Comment: I've made some minor edits, and I also changed around the multiplying by `sizeof` - it's good practice to put the `sizeof` first, which matters when the number of elements itself is a product (because multiply associates to the left, and we want intermediates to be at least `size_t`).

Comment: Disagree with "current code may not work properly on all computers"   A compliant compiler will convert the `0` to `0.0f` and then do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

## Always check whether I/O operations were successful

Code like this is problematic:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
fprintf(fp,"X,Y,Z\n");
```

If we failed to open the file we'll get a NULL pointer assigned to `fp`.  If we're really unlucky, the program will survive passing that to `fprintf()`, and we'll have *no indication that the data were not saved*.  That can be a serious issue if it means that the user believes their data have been safely stored.

Similarly, we should check the return value of `sscanf()` when used on the arguments, before we attempt to use the values we read.  (Alternative - consider `strtoul()` or `strtoul()`, so we can validate that there's no junk following a valid number).

Answer (score 0):

### float v double

Variables are `float` yet constants (`0.4`, `0.1`,...) and functions (`sin(), cos()`) are double.  It would make more consistent to use `float` or `double` throughout.

```
 float xc, time, z;
 xc = 0.5f + 0.1f*sinf(0.04f*time + 10.0f*z); 
 // or 
 double xc, time, z;
 xc = 0.5 + 0.1*sin(0.04*time + 10.0*z);
```

### accuracy v speed

`hypot()` is usual more accurate, although sometime slower than posted code.

```
temp = sqrt( (y-yc)*(y-yc) + (x-xc)*(x-xc) );
// Alternative: 
temp = hypot(y-yc, x-xc);
temp = hypotf(y-yc, x-xc);  // using float only.
```

### %f v %g

Recall that floating point numbers have a *floating* point.  With `"%f"`, large numbers will print with many unnecessary characters and small numbers will   print `0.000000`.  It is more informative (especially during debug) to print the leading digits than to a fixed decimal point format.  Suggest using `"%g"` or `"%e"`.

```
// fprintf(fp,"%f",sally[i]);
fprintf(fp,"%g",sally[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Inconsistent/lack of spacing**

Please, don't do it like this: `0.1 + 0.4 * z*z + 0.1 * z * sin(8.0*z);`, surround all the mathematical operators with spaces everywhere. Not just in random places.

**Comments**

Please, don't add wall of comments between function definition and it's body. It's really hard to read. Usually the function is commented BEFORE the function definition, so... following would be prefered:

```
/*
*  Gen_Sally creates a vector field of dimension [xs,ys,zs,3] from
*  a proceedural function. By passing in different time arguements,
*  a slightly different and rotating field is created.
*  @param[in] 
*  ...
*  @param[out]
*/
void gen_sally(int xs, int ys, int zs, int time, float *sally)
```

Following comments also are quite messy to read:

```
 z = iz * zdelta;                        // map z to 0->1
 xc = 0.5 + 0.1*sin(0.04*time+10.0*z);   // For each z-slice, determine the spiral circle.
 yc = 0.5 + 0.1*cos(0.03*time+3.0*z);    //    (xc,yc) determine the center of the circle.
 r = 0.1 + 0.4 * z*z + 0.1 * z * sin(8.0*z); //  The radius also changes at each z-slice.
 r2 = 0.2 + 0.1*z;                           //    r is the center radius, r2 is for damping
```

Line breaks, etc. Why not just picking better names for variables instead? And describing everything what's gonna happen before actual code?

**Sanity check**

Your not checking for NULL pointer, invalid values, etc. None of Your functions can fail and return error, etc

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as i said in the question, the part of the code that you're commenting on is of my lecturers. Where as mine is below, that's the code i want to improve.

Comment: sorry, missed that part :)